# How can I change the width and height of a textfield in Vuetify?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I would like to change the width as well as the height of the `<v-text-field>`tag.

I've already tried doing it with *.css* but it doesn't change the parameters of the actual textfield, instead it only changes some kinds of invisible parameters which result in big white spaces on my page.

This is what I've already tried.

```
<template>
  <v-text-field class="first"></v-text-field>
</template>

<style>
  .first {
    width: 150px !important;
    height: 350px !important
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add CSS rules to change the `v-text-field` height, you could simply use the `height` prop like :

```
  <v-text-field height="350"></v-text-field>
```

but your component should be placed inside the `template` not in `script` tag :

```
 <template>
  <v-text-field height="350"></v-text-field>
 </template>
```

Comment: Okay why I haven't thought of that, I don't know... I feel so dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Try having a wrapper above v-text-field and apply styles required.

```
   <div class="first">
    <v-text-field></v-text-field>
    </div>
```