# Set height vuetify textfield according to design

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have vuetify textfield with 1.5.x version in my codepen: https://codepen.io/handy29/pen/yLLwjGg but the height of textfield is not according to my design [image: textfield design]. I also already follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57891156/how-can-i-change-the-width-and-height-of-a-textfield-in-vuetify) as you can see in my code (html) the text field is still the same. My code so far in css:

```
.theme--light.v-text-field--outline > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot {
    border-width: 1px;
  }

.theme--light.v-text-field--outline:not(.v-input--is-focused):not(.v-input--has-state)>.v-input__control>.v-input__slot:hover{
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
  border-color: #6fbd44;

}
```

my code in html:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-form>
      <v-container>
        <v-layout row wrap>

          <v-flex xs12 sm6 md3>
            <v-text-field
              width="700px;"
              height="-1"
              outline
              single-line
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-flex>


        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

what should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must unset css property `min-height` in the `v-input__slot` class and set the `height` property:

```css
.v-input__slot {
 min-height: unset;
 height: 30px;
}
```